# ng-minlength is valid when length is 0

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and stumbled upon a validation problem in a form.
Below is my input field and when I don't enter any value it show's as valid and also 'ng-valid' class is added to it even though I've defined minlength to be 5

```
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="formdata.name" ng-minlength=5 />
```

It happens even in angular example - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to set the `ngRequired` parameter as well. Without it the minlength parameter means that **if** the user has entered a value it must be at least 5 characters long, but it's ok to leave the field empty.

```
<input 
    id="name" 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Name" 
    ng-model="formdata.name" 
    ng-minlength="5" 
    ng-required="true" />
```

Comment: What would it be if the requirement was the same except for to allow the field to be empty?

Comment: @Carnotaurus Well then you would just not use `ngRequired`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant not allow the field to be empty - it only shows an error once I begin to type in the input box

Comment: You're going to have to post a new question about that, including your HTML.

Comment: Annoying; the existence of the property `ng-required` should be enough to make it work - that's how HTML works, anyway (implicitly true). I was leaving it out and wondering why it was broken!